# Regex returning empty strings

Tags: php, regex, json

I have following code:

```
preg_match_all('/"([^"]*)"/', $json , $results);
var_dump($json);var_dump($results);die();
```

At this point a dump of `$json` has

```
string(423) "{"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51Lg%2Bd4cqRL._SX355_.jpg";[355,266],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51Lg%2Bd4cqRL._SX425_.jpg":[425,319],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51Lg%2Bd4cqRL._SX466_.jpg":[466,350],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51Lg%2Bd4cqRL._SX450_.jpg":[450,338],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51Lg%2Bd4cqRL.jpg":[500,375]}"
```

I’m trying to get the links. I’ve tried `json_decode` but I get error number 4 which is incorrect syntax. There are no invisible characters in front or after the JSON on the string. Without luck i decided to try to regex my way into it but the above code returns

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> array(0) { } }
```

Any help to get the first first would be greatly appreciated.

Ok, as some of you noted this is basically a hack to get it to work no matter what. If you are interested in doing it right here’s the full info:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00BEL2G4C/ref=s9_wish_gw_d31_g21_i3?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=desktop-1&pf_rd_r=1VPYMKFSFN5BRHD4AD3W&pf_rd_t=36701&pf_rd_p=1970559082&pf_rd_i=desktop");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0");
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);

$html = $html->load($curl_scraped_page);
$json = $html->find('#imageBlock', 0)->children[0]->children[0]->children[1]->children[1]->children[0]->children[2]->children[0]->children[0]->children[0]->children[0]->children[0]->attr['data-a-dynamic-image'];

$json = utf8_encode($json);
var_dump(json_decode($json));var_dump(json_last_error());die();
```

I know that Amazon has an API but they are annoying and will only let you use it if you are an affiliate and they don’t accept under construction websites as affiliates so I’m just trying to get this out and will change it to the API once site goes live and gets approved for Amazon affiliates.

The URL is actually dynamic, just used a static one for testing purposes.
I would *love* to find a JSON solution as that would be much cleaner.

Comment: Why not parse the JSON into an array? That would make your data easier to get to, rather than regexing the string.

Comment: I tried that and got incorrect syntax error even though I checked with json lint and it is a valid json :( I would take a solution to that instead if you have one :)

Comment: So instead of doing it the right way by figuring out why jsode_decode() does not work, you decide to hack it the ugly way?

Comment: `json_decode()` worked fine for me (PHP 5.5.19)

Comment: Check this out: http://3v4l.org/O9bIo. It seems to work without problems on all PHP versions since 5.2.0 (when `json_decode()` was introduced).

Comment: I would still try to make json_decode() work. Where does the data come from? It might have incorrect encoding and you'd need to use utf8_encode() first. Have a look at these two links: - [Make sure the input was encoded with the correct charset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php#85980)
- [Make sure you pass in utf8 content](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php#86997)

Comment: if i copy and paste the json in code then it works but when getting dynamically it doesnt :(

Answer (score 2):

Do this -

```
$parsed = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($parsed as $row=>$value){
    echo $row .'<br>';
}
```

[EXAMPLE](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/vhc5-n490)

Comment: got "NULL" :( i tried this before, even using utf8_encode

Comment: Did you look at the example? How is the code, for the JSON string, different @bia.migueis?

Comment: im not sure how its different. it seems the same but then i might have some invisible characters somewhere i can't find. I updated the question with info on how i get the json.

Comment: Can you recreate the problem at PHP Fiddle?

Comment: hmm first time using fiddle so forgive me for any mistakes: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/bqys-5272

Comment: Drat, the cURL will not work there so we'll need the static JSON.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66683/discussion-between-bia-migueis-and-jay-blanchard).

Comment: I cannot chat from this computer, it's not allowed. I updated your code and it works - http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/wumt-d0xs The only thing I can think of is that your cURL is not returning anything. Have you checked `$curl_scraped_page`, etc.?

Comment: the json i provided is actually a dump of $curl_scraped_page. it totally works if i just copy the jason and paste it in code. it just doesnt work when i use the curl even tho its returning stuff and i even tried the utf8_encode() before doing the json_decode()

Comment: Without being able to run it there is not much I can do to help. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it isn't working. This works for me:

```
<?php

$json ='{"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51Lg%2Bd4cqRL._SX355_.jpg":           [355,266],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51Lg%2Bd4cqRL._SX425_.jpg":[425,319],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51Lg%2Bd4cqRL._SX466_.jpg":[466,350],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51Lg%2Bd4cqRL._SX450_.jpg":[450,338],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51Lg%2Bd4cqRL.jpg":[500,375]}';

 preg_match_all('/"([^"]*)"/', $json , $results);
 var_dump($json);var_dump($results);die();
?>
```

The output is:

```
    gregp:~ greg$ php ./test.preg.php 
string(373) "{"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51Lg%2Bd4cqRL._SX355_.jpg":[355,266],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51Lg%2Bd4cqRL._SX425_.jpg":[425,319],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51Lg%2Bd4cqRL._SX466_.jpg":[466,350],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51Lg%2Bd4cqRL._SX450_.jpg":[450,338],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51Lg%2Bd4cqRL.jpg":[500,375]}"
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(65) ""http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51Lg%2Bd4cqRL._SX355_.jpg""
    [1]=>
    string(65) ""http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51Lg%2Bd4cqRL._SX425_.jpg""
    [2]=>
    string(65) ""http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51Lg%2Bd4cqRL._SX466_.jpg""
    [3]=>
    string(65) ""http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51Lg%2Bd4cqRL._SX450_.jpg""
    [4]=>
    string(57) ""http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51Lg%2Bd4cqRL.jpg""
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(63) "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51Lg%2Bd4cqRL._SX355_.jpg"
    [1]=>
    string(63) "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51Lg%2Bd4cqRL._SX425_.jpg"
    [2]=>
    string(63) "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51Lg%2Bd4cqRL._SX466_.jpg"
    [3]=>
    string(63) "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51Lg%2Bd4cqRL._SX450_.jpg"
    [4]=>
    string(55) "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51Lg%2Bd4cqRL.jpg"
  }
}
```

Comment: yes if i paste the json in a variable and use that it works but it doesnt work when the json comes dynamically

Comment: I would think there is a formatting or charset issue then

Answer (score 1):

Just do a non-greedy match between the "'s

```
preg_match_all('/"(.*?)"/', $json , $results);
var_dump($json);var_dump($results);die();
```

Comment: array(2) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> array(0) { } }

Comment: preg_match_all implies g modifier, or else you would just use preg_match

Answer (score 0):

So I had to do `$json = preg_replace('/&quot;/', '"', $json);` before calling the decode and that fixed my issue.